# Can a molecule be ionized by absorbing the energy of more than 1 photon?

Tags: photons, atomic-physics, molecules

I'm wondering if a molecule can absorb more then 1 photon before releasing a photon. The reason I'm asking is I would like to ionize a molecule with light but the frequency of light this molecule absorbs only has .5eV approx but the ionization energy of the molecule is 13.7 eV . will multiple absorptions have an additive effect on the molecule's energy level if possible?

Comment: You can absorb *lots* of photons - e.g., the Rydberg atoms used in the experiments of Haroche require about 50 photons to be absorbed (since they have angular momentum around 50).

Comment: If you want to ionize an atom or molecule that way, the rate at which photons are being absorbed has to be larger than the rate at which they are being emitted by the excited molecule. If an excited state only lives for a couple ns (or ps...), then one has to supply a second photon within that time, which requires high light intensity. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoionization

Comment: @CuriousOne - in this case, you need about 28 photons in the time, not just two. Indeed it can be done with focused power - just needs more power than you were expecting, perhaps... or you can say it will happen for just a small fraction of the molecules.

Comment: May I ask what molecule this is? I know that hydrogen _atoms_ have an ionization energy of 13.7 eV - but in a gas, they will form _molecules_ with a higher ionization energy (around 15.5 eV). The number just jumped out at me...

Comment: Co2 in gas form just got the number from a quick web search not 100% sure it is correct but the concept is the same

Comment: @Floris: Thanks for clarifying. That's what I meant, I was thinking about two-photon spectroscopy, which in this case is insufficient.

Comment: Multiphoton ionisation of atoms and molecules has been studied experimentally. Do a search on the web to find some literature. You need quite powerful lasers to achieve this goal.